# How can I modify column data for multiple case. (for pyspark)

Tags: pyspark

Let's suppose column 'company_num' has ***5,5,5,1,1,2,2*** in a DataFrame.
I want to add add different number for each company_num.

if who has company_num 5,2 then +2

if who has company_num 1 then +7

I expect final company_num change to ***7,7,7,8,8,4,4***

to solve this I tried like :

```
 new = (
    df
    .where("company_num in (5,2)")
    .withColumn('company_num', (col('company_num')+2).cast('integer'))
    .where("company_num in (1)")
    .withColumn('company_num', (col('company_num')+7).cast('integer'))
    )
```

but, this was not work properly

Comment: have you tried using udf?

Comment: Can you please provide a clear example of input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `when`, not `where`, to perform conditional updates:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'company_num', 
    F.when(F.col('company_num').isin(5,2), F.col('company_num')+2)
     .when(F.col('company_num') == 1, F.col('company_num')+7)
     .otherwise(F.col('company_num'))
)

df2.show()
+-----------+
|company_num|
+-----------+
|          7|
|          7|
|          7|
|          8|
|          8|
|          4|
|          4|
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

this code might be useful.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import when
>>> data = [5,5,5,1,1,2,2]
>>> input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, IntegerType())
>>> input_df.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    5|
|    5|
|    5|
|    1|
|    1|
|    2|
|    2|
+-----+

>>> input_df.withColumn("new_value", when(input_df.value.isin(5, 2), input_df.value+2).otherwise(when(input_df.value == 1, input_df.value+7))).show()
+-----+---------+
|value|new_value|
+-----+---------+
|    5|        7|
|    5|        7|
|    5|        7|
|    1|        8|
|    1|        8|
|    2|        4|
|    2|        4|
+-----+---------+
```